# Bulk updation not happening

Tags: elasticsearch

Im posting the following data to update using bulk API.

```
 {"_index":"false-matter-alert","_type":"eventlog","_id":"AVJDZBZ-cQ6ZeQVtbZkW","_retry_on_conflict":3} 
    {"doc":{"tier":"WEB SERVICE","doc_as_upsert":true}}
    {"_index":"false-matter-alert","_type":"eventlog","_id":"AVJDZBZ-cQ6ZeQVtbZka","_retry_on_conflict":3} 
    {"doc":{"tier":"WEB SERVICE","doc_as_upsert":true}} 
    {"_index":"false-matter-alert","_type":"eventlog","_id":"AVJDZBZ-cQ6ZeQVtbZkf","_retry_on_conflict":3} 
    {"doc":{"tier":"WEB SERVICE","doc_as_upsert":true}}
```

But after posting Iam getting the following error

```
  {
        "error": "ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[No feature for name [_bulk]]",
        "status": 400
    }
```

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Can you also show the URL you're POSTing to?

Comment: Also `doc_as_upsert` needs to be at the same level as the `doc` element, i.e. not contained in `doc`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update a doc using Bulk request you need to specify the `update` action first like that:

```
  {"update" : { "_index":"false-matter-alert","_type":"eventlog","_id":"AVJDZBZ-cQ6ZeQVtbZkW","_retry_on_conflict":3} }
{"doc":{"tier":"WEB SERVICE","doc_as_upsert":true}}
{"update" : {"_index":"false-matter-alert","_type":"eventlog","_id":"AVJDZBZ-cQ6ZeQVtbZka","_retry_on_conflict":3} }
{"doc":{"tier":"WEB SERVICE","doc_as_upsert":true}} 
{"update" : {"_index":"false-matter-alert","_type":"eventlog","_id":"AVJDZBZ-cQ6ZeQVtbZkf","_retry_on_conflict":3} }
{"doc":{"tier":"WEB SERVICE","doc_as_upsert":true}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The format in which you are sending the data is not correct. You need to specify which action you are going to perform while using bulk operation.
Since you are trying to update, your data format should be looking like below:

```
{"update":{"_index":"false-matter-alert","_type":"eventlog","_id":"AVJDZBZ-cQ6ZeQVtbZkW","_retry_on_conflict":3}} 
{"doc":{"tier":"WEB SERVICE","doc_as_upsert":true}}
{"update":{"_index":"false-matter-alert","_type":"eventlog","_id":"AVJDZBZ-cQ6ZeQVtbZka","_retry_on_conflict":3}} 
{"doc":{"tier":"WEB SERVICE","doc_as_upsert":true}} 
{"update": {"_index":"false-matter-alert","_type":"eventlog","_id":"AVJDZBZ-cQ6ZeQVtbZkf","_retry_on_conflict":3}} 
{"doc":{"tier":"WEB SERVICE","doc_as_upsert":true}}
```

For more details regarding the formats please check the documentation of bulk API [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html)